# C# Entity Framework use SQL options/hints

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-optimization, query-hints

I am working on some search optimizations in a WPF application.

There is a search XAML view, that uses a SQL Server view with `IQueryable`.

In SQL Server, I can use `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 8649)` when I get the `SELECT` part from the view, but in the view itself, I can't use it. This `OPTION` speeds up my query more than 3 times. I clear cache each time I execute it.

Because of this SQL Server view's limitation, I need to somehow add this to C# code.

So, how can I add this `OPTION` to be used in `IQueryable`?

Comment: EF is not the best approach for complex querying in any case. We use EF only for CRUD. For searches we build custom queries dynamically. Everything starts with taken path. I believe, you took wrong path from the start. Now, you've mentioned a view. So, if you delegated query to a view, what is the problem to create this view with all needed hints in the view?

Comment: When I tried to add this OPTION into VIEW it says that 'alter view must be the only statement in the batch'

Comment: 'alter view must be the only statement in the batch' means you need to have a GO statement between the ALTER and any other statement.

Comment: But OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 8649) should be part of the SELECT in VIEW. And also, I tried to add GO, but with no luck. If you have any example where that works, it would be nice to see it.

Comment: No ... it means that there is another statement in your script besides the ALTER VIEW statement.

Comment: You could post the View Script you are using and I could look it over ...

Comment: If you have any working example of Alter/Create view with this option it would fix my issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218394/discussion-between-user3239349-and-jason).

Answer (score 1):

You can add query hints by using interceptor.

Read details from this [sample by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-command-interception-to-add-query-hints).

Also, you have to register interceptor class like this.

```
private void DependencyInjection(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddDbContext<SampleDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer("some connection string") 
                       .AddInterceptors(new TaggedQueryCommandInterceptor())
 );
}
```